# How to smooth the edges around an oval in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas, antialiasing

I am kind of new to **tkinter** and I recently learned about the **canvas** widget. After getting the basics down I thought that I could use canvas to make a **custom progress bar** and it worked! It is really awesome, however, after removing the outline on the shapes I saw that the edges of the shapes were pretty rough especially the ovals. I did a bit of search and just found out that you could use the **smooth** keyword argument only with polygons. So my question is that is there a way to smooth the edges of shapes especially ovals in tkinter, kind of like **anti-aliasing**? My code:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")
percent = 0
progress_done, new_oval = None, None
canvas = Canvas(root, width=400, height=400, bg="white")
canvas.pack(pady=10)
prg_bar = canvas.create_rectangle(50, 140, 350, 160, fill="grey", outline="")
oval_one = canvas.create_oval(40, 140, 60, 160, fill="grey", outline="", )
oval_two = canvas.create_oval(340, 140, 360, 160, fill="grey", outline="")


def add_up():
    global percent, progress_done, new_oval
    if percent < 100:
        percent += 20
        if progress_done is None and new_oval is None:
            canvas.create_oval(40, 140, 60, 160, fill="light blue", outline='')
            canvas.delete(oval_one)
            progress_done = canvas.create_rectangle(50, 140, (percent * 3) + 50, 160, fill="light blue", outline="")
            new_oval = canvas.create_oval((percent * 3) + 40, 140, (percent * 3) + 60, 160, fill="light blue",
                                          outline="")
        else:
            canvas.delete(progress_done)
            canvas.delete(new_oval)
            progress_done = canvas.create_rectangle(50, 140, (percent * 3) + 50, 160, fill="light blue", outline="")
            new_oval = canvas.create_oval((percent * 3) + 40, 140, (percent * 3) + 60, 160, fill="light blue",
                                          outline="")
            if percent == 100:
                canvas.delete(oval_two)


btn = Button(root, text="Add to prg", command=add_up)
btn.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Short answer, no.

Comment: Draw your oval with a polygon.

Comment: @Michael Guidry, I have tried that. The entire canvas shapes are low resolution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Draw your oval with `create_polygon`. Below is an example of drawing an oval and a round rect. Both examples set the `splinesteps` option to enhance the smoothness of the generated curves. The `splinesteps` option defaults to 12.

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()

c = tk.Canvas(root)
c.pack(fill='both', expand=True, anchor='nw')

def poly_oval(x, y, width, height, resolution=32):
    points = [x, y,
              x+width, y,
              x+width, y+height,
              x, y+height,
              x, y]
              
    return c.create_polygon(points, fill='#f00', smooth=True, splinesteps=resolution)   
    
def poly_roundrect(x, y, width, height, radius, resolution=32):
    #this is not a true round rect
    #it's a round rect with the potential to have invisible garbage that cheats
    #it cheats convincingly if you don't use an outline when it is cheating
    radius = min(min(width, height), radius*2)
    points = [x, y,
              x+radius, y,
              x+(width-radius), y,
              x+width, y,
              x+width, y+radius,
              x+width, y+(height-radius),
              x+width, y+height,
              x+(width-radius), y+height,
              x+radius, y+height,
              x, y+height,
              x, y+(height-radius),
              x, y+radius,
              x, y]
              
    rect = c.create_polygon(points, fill='#1f1', smooth=True, splinesteps=resolution) 
    
    #display vertices
    #for i in range(0, len(points), 2):
    #    poly_oval(points[i]-2, points[i+1]-2, 4, 4)
              
    return rect
    
rect = poly_roundrect(10, 10, 300, 50, 10, 64)

root.mainloop()
```