# Smoothen the Outline of Tkinter Circle Graphic

Tags: tkinter, geometry, tkinter-canvas

Below is a pared down copy of the code used for creating a circle in Tkinter using Python. I have the method `self.drawCircle()` which uses the `create_oval()` function on the canvas `self.c`. As you will see when you run the program, the circle is not very clear. There are many jagged edges in the final display. For example if you look at the 4 cardinal points on the circle, NSEW, all of them show a flat line of roughly 10 pixels long rather than a nice smooth curve.

Is there a way to create a smoother circle?

```py
from tkinter import *

class MainWindow:
    def __init__(self, master):
        # Master Window
        self.master = master
        # Instantiate frames
        self.frame0 = Frame(self.master, bd=5, padx=5, bg='#448833') # Top long row

        # Place frames
        self.frame0.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky="nsew")
        self.drawCircle(100, 100, 300, 300,10)  # draws circle 

    def drawCircle(self,x1,y1,x2,y2, width):
        ''' inputs: 4 ints: coordinates of square, top left, and bottom right.'''

        # Create a canvas object
        self.c = Canvas(self.frame0, width=500, height=400, bg='white')

        # Draw an Oval in the canvas
        self.c.create_oval(x1,y1,x2,y2, width=width)
        
        self.c.grid(row=1,column=2,sticky='nse')

def main():
    root = Tk()
    MainWindow(root)

    root.mainloop()

main()
```

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64773958/16775594) help?